# How to select vertices by their color?

Tags: python, vertices, color

I know this has been asked, but the answer form here: https://gist.github.com/tamask/2590850 doesn't work for me. I get an "out of range error" in the first loop.
I tried modifying a solution from here: [Vertices—loop indices vs. unique indices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119599/vertices-loop-indices-vs-unique-indices) but nothing.
Here's the code:

```
import bpy
from collections import defaultdict

obj = bpy.context.active_object
col = obj.data.vertex_colors.active
polygons = obj.data.polygons

color = (0, 1, 0, 0)

vertex_map = defaultdict(list)

for poly in polygons:
    for v_ix, l_ix in zip(poly.vertices, poly.loop_indices):
        vertex_map[v_ix].append(l_ix)
  
for v_ix, l_ixs in vertex_map.items():
    for l_ix in l_ixs:

        if col.data[l_ix].color == color:
            
            obj.data.vertices[v_ix].select = True
```

I would really appreaciate any help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73846/how-to-compare-colour-values-in-blender-using-python

Answer (score 1):

It is a comparison issue.

```
col.data[l_ix].color == color
```

You can:

```
from mathutils import Vector

color = Vector((0, 1, 0, 0))
```

Then compare with:

```
color == Vector(col.data[l_ix].color)
```

Alternatively, to avoid rounding issues, define an epsilon and compare using:

```
(color - Vector(col.data[l_ix].color)).length_squared < some_epsilon
```